# Override SQL generated by LINQ to SQL?

Tags: linq-to-sql

Is it possible to override the SQL generated by LINQ to SQL, for optimisation purposes?

Comment: Depending on your use case, it may be possible but, IMHO, you have to ask yourself why you need to do this? 

L2S is for dynamically generating sql so you don't have to write it.  If you are going to write it anyway, no need to override anything. Just implement it. yetapb has given you a suggestion but you could take any number of angles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [ExecuteQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.executequery.aspx) method instead. This is useful if you want to leverage a function that's available in SqlServer but not in Linq (IE PIVOT, etc...)

For instance:

```
var query = db.ExecuteQuery<MyType>( @"SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ...");
```

Answer (score 2):

One way I have used:
Create a stored proc, use the linq to sql designer to drag the proc into the design surface.  Call the resulting method instead.